# HtmlAgility problem

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

i am trying to extract some data between divs.

```
<div class="movie_general"><div class="img"><a href="/Movies.html" title="Watch Movie">
```

Fore example if i want the link "/Movies.html" i used:

```
string hrefValue = doc.DocumentNode
            .Descendants("div")
            .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "movie_general")
            .Select(x => x.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

             MessageBox.Show(hrefValue);
```

but i get a NullReferenceException at Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "movie_general")

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the Linq provider must iterate through all other nodes in the document to check if it matches your search. This document must have at least one `div` which does not have a `class` attribute. So, the error happens by trying to read the `Value` property of an attribute which does not exist.

Replace this

```
.Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "movie_general")
.Select(x => x.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value)
```

with this

```
.Where(x => x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "movie_general")
.Select(x => x.Element("a") != null && x.Element("a").Attributes["href"] != null ? x.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value : string.Empty)
```

Comment: now null exception at .Select(x => x.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value) lol

Comment: do we need to put a null check here too?

Comment: Yes, you have to. It's the same problem. A div whti no `a` nodes inside it will trigger another NullReferenceException.

Comment: I changed my answer so it now covers the `Select` problem.

Comment: now it says :Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: I changed my answer again. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the class and that the a tag is subordinate to that, why not just grab it directly using:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\temp\\stackhtml.html");
    string link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='movie_general']//a").GetAttributeValue("href", "unkown");
    Console.WriteLine(link);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

and the result:

[image]

I added closing div tags to your example so that I could scrape it and dumped it in a file on my c drive:

```
<div class="movie_general">
   <div class="img">
      <a href="/Movies.html" title="Watch Movie">
    </div>
</div>
```